# Prove trigonometric inequality $\cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I have a following expression $$\cos(x)>1-\frac{1}{2}x^2$$
For all $x>0.$
How to prove it?

Comment: A first step would be to reduce the problem to an interval where the inequality is not obvious. (And yes, as second comment says, you should show some of your work when asking questions here)

Comment: What do you know? What did you try?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Taylor's Theorem with Lagrange form remainder, for example?

Comment: I need to prove it as elementary as possible. I wanted to use trigonomteric "one" identity or other but I think I'm gonna need to use a method from calculus which I dont even know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)=\cos x-1+x^2/2 \implies f'(x)= x-\sin x \ge 0$ So $f(x)$ is an increasing function. This means that for $x>0, f(x) \ge f(0)=0 \implies f(x) \ge 1-x^2/2.$

Comment: Where can  I see theory for this method?

Comment: this is in the chapter of monotonicity in calculus.